# Traversing to other nodes in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I must be missing something, but I have a theory and wanted to figure out why I cannot find other groups in Cypher that share topics of other groups.

```
MATCH(g:Group{group_slug:"um-mobile-apps"})<-[:TOPIC_OF]-(t:Topic)-[:TOPIC_OF]->(og:Group)
WHERE NOT g.group_slug = 'um-mobile-apps'
RETURN og.group_name
```

It should return one other group that matches 2 topics but it only returns itself if I remove the NOT condition. Is it because of the directions of the Topic node pointing to the group and not the other way? Something like: `(g)-[:TOPIC_OF]->(t)<-[:TOPIC_OF]-(og)?`

The goal is to find all groups that share the same topics as the starting node. Bonus points for if there is way to rank them by most Topics in common. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be following to filter starting Node.

```
MATCH(g:Group{group_slug:"um-mobile-apps"})<-[:TOPIC_OF]-(t:Topic)-[:TOPIC_OF]->(og:Group)
WHERE NOT og.group_slug = "um-mobile-apps"
RETURN og.group_name
```

For the score it will be something like

```
MATCH(g:Group{group_slug:"um-mobile-apps"})<-[:TOPIC_OF]-(t:Topic)-[:TOPIC_OF]->(og:Group)
WHERE NOT og.group_slug = "um-mobile-apps"
RETURN og.group_name, count(t)
ORDER BY count(t) DESC
```